# Why System.IO.Directory.Delete(string,bool) only markes a folder as deleted, when a asp.net site impersonates a user

Tags: .net, iis-7.5, windows-10, delete-file, impersonation

I have a strange behavior in my `asp.net 4.0 Application`, since i have updated to Windows10 (i think it came with 10).

I have an application which uses `BasicAuthentication` in IIS - in my `Login.aspx` i'm manually `verifying` the `user` and the `password` against a defined AD-Domain.
If the credentials are valid, i store a simple object with some userdata in the session & redirect to my the mainpage.

So far so good - With the application the user is able to delete files & directories. These operations are always `performed under` a `impersonation context` of the current user.

**Entering "Impersonation Context":** (main parts only)

```
[PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
public virtual void Enter(LogonType logonType = LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LogonProvider provider = LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT)
{       
    token = IntPtr.Zero;

    //Create the token
    bool logonSuccessfull = GetToken(this.username, this.password, this.domain, ref token, logonType, provider);

    WindowsIdentity identity;
    identity = new WindowsIdentity(token);
    impContext = identity.Impersonate();                               
}
```

**if the user deletes a Directory:**

```
Public void Delete(string directory)
{
    //1. Entering impersonation context before (context.Enter();)

    //2. Delete the file (executing this basic .net method):
      System.IO.Directory.Delete(directory, true);

    //3. Leaving the impersonation context after (context.Leave() -> .Undo();)
}
```

After that operation `i can still see the directory` as administrator in the explorer (which was closed before).  But if i want to open the folder, i get a `access denied` message. I'm also `not able to` watch the permissions of the directory or `become the owner` of this 'ghost-folder'. A quick filesystem check didn't helped too.

**But:** If the `applicationpool ends` - **the folders are gone**...

The Applicationpool is a `Classic .net 4.0` Pool with `Network-Identity` (changeing this settings did not solved the problem at this point)

Has anyone an idea why they do not get deleted immediately?
& how can i force it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least i found the Issue.
The problem was, that i have invoked the `Impersonation` `twice or more` in some cases. 
So i was already in an impersonation state and called the impersonation code again...
This was not a problem before Windows 10 but after as it seems..